# Why are there extra untagged 'images' in Amazon ECR after doing docker push?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I've pushed some Docker images to Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR), and I'm not sure why there are extra untagged images.

This happens for multiple of my images but one of my images is just `redhat/ubi9` + Java, etc. and looks like this:

```
ARG CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URI

FROM ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URI}my-ubi9-base:latest
ENV BUILD_VERSION=unknown
RUN ...
WORKDIR /opt/my-org/api
ADD --chmod=740 <<EOF run
...
EOF
SHELL ["/usr/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT /opt/my-org/api/run
EXPOSE 80
```

Result after `docker push`ing this image:

[image: API base image]

Comment: What is your build command? tags are independent of the Dockerfile, so passing no tags will tag the newest one as `latest` and that tag will move to it after pushing, since image tags are unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: The ECR console is showing provenance attestations, which can be disabled via passing [`--provenance=false`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#provenance) to [`docker buildx build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/)**

---

This is a poor UX decision, and is related to the way ECR shows

1. [multi-architecture container images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-multi-architecture-container-images-for-amazon-ecr/)
2. provenance attestations, enabled by default in Buildx versions v0.10.0 and higher

A proposal to improve it is still [pending since Dec 2021](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1596).

One way this could happen, is when pushing multi-arch container images<sup>1</sup>. However, this doesn't seem to be the case here as you've got an entry with a file size of 0 MB.

Essentially, the console shows everything ungrouped - images, artifacts and indexes. As per the Docker docs, [attestations (both SBOM and provenance) attach to images as a manifest in the image index](https://docs.docker.com/build/attestations/#storage).

Since it's a manifest, the console is also showing the build [provenance attestations](https://docs.docker.com/build/attestations/slsa-provenance/). It's correctly marked as '0 MB' since it *is* less than a MB albeit misleading. However, it is incorrectly labelled as an 'image'.

If you'd like to disable them, pass [`--provenance=false`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#provenance) as an option to your [`docker buildx build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/) to prevent them from being created and added.

The console has long needed improvements for showing [OS/arch](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1591) correctly like [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-cli/latest/images/sha256-5dc317a68c6f412fa9def52f8984b2cd034e14d5b51a1470de9d807c6802094b?context=explore) does, as well as these type of artifacts correctly.

---

<sup>1</sup> You normally also see untagged images when you've pushed a container image which supports multi-arch via a component known as a [manifest list (or image index)](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/). This results in an entry with artifact type of 'Image Index'. However, container images aren't typically smaller than a megabyte.

You can also confirm this using `aws ecr --region xxx describe-images --repository-name xxx`, which will show you the 2 images the (instruction set) architecture as a tag in `imageTags`.

For a multiplatform image with 2 supported architectures, it would show up as three things in the view:

- Image Index (manifest list)
- Image A supporting arch A (with file size of not 0)
- Image B supporting arch B (with file size of not 0)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!